# How to login as multiple users in multiple browser tabs?

Tags: authentication, session-state

As a high level administrator I have option to login as an other administrator by setting proper session. To develop this option I want to be able to login as multiple admins and jump between their account **where some browser tab may be involved in account 1 when other tab involves in account 2** (something like Gmail multiple user login).

How should I manage this? using session (session changes in all tabs)? cookies (So which tab read which cookies?), server object? passing a query string between pages? or what?

Comment: why don't you propose to use multiple browsers ?

Comment: Yes. Currently I do this. But Google multiple login system is blinking to me ;)